# Adding a payment gateway to Quickbooks POS

Tags: java, quickbooks

Please i will like to find out if it is possible to add a custom payment gateway to quick books POS. By custom payment gateway i mean postilion or Trade root. Trade root for example connects using a socket which i can write, so i want to know if this can be done in quick books POS software as i have already implemented in an application( I got the source codes for it).

I have read the quickbooks api and documentation but it isn't so clear and i can't get much information on this from the quickbooks retailer in my locality.

I hope i get to

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Please i will like to find out if it is possible to add a custom payment gateway to quick books POS.

No, it's not.